# When importing Excel Data to Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, import-from-excel

When importing Excel Data 2.01805E+19 to Oracle table it taking as it is not as 20180530997401900000

Comment: Select the data and change number format to Number from Scientific in excel sheet home. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change data type from numeric to text in excel, then import into table in oracle. Field in oracle must be varchar2 type. After you can transform varchar2 type to number type in oracle database.